# XML Schema Use Attribute Cannot Appear in Element

Tags: xml, xsd

So when I put in the `use ="required"` attribute into my schema for an XML assignment, I get the following message:

> s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'use' cannot appear in element
>   'element'.

What does it mean? It doesn't seem to be affecting my code at all, and the use attribute is required for this assignment.

Schema Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Inventory">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Items" use="required">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="PartID" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
          <xs:element name="Part_Desc" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
          <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:decimal" use="required"/>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                 <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                </xs:restriction>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="vendor_id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
       </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Inventory xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="exam.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<Items vendor_id="2">        
<PartID>a101</PartID>       
<Part_Desc>Keyboard</Part_Desc>        
<Price>79.99</Price>    
</Items>    

 <Items vendor_id="5">        
 <PartID>a404</PartID>        
 <Part_Desc>Wireless Mouse</Part_Desc>        
 <Price>59.99</Price>    
 </Items>    

 <Items vendor_id="3">        
 <PartID>a120</PartID>       
 <Part_Desc>2 GB USB Drive</Part_Desc>        
 <Price>18.99</Price>   
 </Items>    

 <Items vendor_id="8">        
 <PartID>c506</PartID>   
 <Part_Desc>24" Monitor</Part_Desc>        
 <Price>459.99</Price>  
 </Items>

 </Inventory>
```

The code seems to work still, there are not errors.

Comment: how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `use` attribute is valid only for `xs:attribute` elements.

If you want to specify that an element is mandatory or optional use the `minOccurs` attribute.

Element required:

```
<xs:element name="PartID" type="xs:ID" minOccurs="1"/>
```

Element optional:

```
<xs:element name="PartID" type="xs:ID" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Note that by default `minOccurs` is `1`, whereas by default `use` is `optional`.

**UPDATE**

The use of `restriction` requires the definition of a (simple) type. This:

```
 <xs:element name="Price" minOccurs="1">
   <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
       <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
     </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
 </xs:element>
```

defines `Price` to be a decimal with 2 digits for the fraction part.

Comment: Thanks, but now when I take out the use attribute in my elements, and either leave it blank or put in minOccurs, I get a message saying xs:restriction is not allowed.  But again, it appears nothing errors out.

Comment: I added an explanation on how to use `restriction`. I don't know what are you using for the validation, but as long as the schema itself is not valid (as it was the case), the validation program should just reject it and do not do any validation of the XML.

Comment: Thanks again.  I am using a program called Editix.  Free download for XML editor.